# The galaxy s3 wont take picture

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

So i'm trying to run picture capture to load image into imageview, it works fine on samsung galaxy mini and galaxy one, however on samsung galaxy s3 it crashes when returning to the app.
my code to start the activity:

```
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 11);
```

And code where i recieve activity result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 11) { 
        ImageView slika=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nesrecaSlika1);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");            
        slika.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
```

However when i was debugging there is no error in the code, but app just crashes on return. If i go back without taking picture it works fine on. In my logcat i get that problem:

```
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:702)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:316)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:143)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1001)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:858)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:822)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at com.motiviti.zmapp.MainActivity.showPopup(MainActivity.java:310)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at com.motiviti.zmapp.MainActivity.access$10(MainActivity.java:297)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at com.motiviti.zmapp.MainActivity$8.run(MainActivity.java:287)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
11-14 16:39:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(19745):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas what it might be?

I jsut tested with that code:

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivity(cameraIntent);
```

And steal it crashes when returning to my app.

Comment: What is the code at the line at com.motiviti.zmapp.MainActivity.showPopup(MainActivity.java:310) ?

Comment: popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.FILL, 0, -30);   but that code is excecuted only when app starts.

Comment: Ok i deletet that code now my app doesn't crash but it looks like it's been restarted, because my oncreate code is called when comming back. Any ideas why???

Comment: Why minus wote? i think i explained my question well enough, however i didnt get a solution.

Comment: Hi Gabrjan, your question is valid and i am facing same issue, did you find solution to this issue , please post answer.

Comment: Well i didn't find a solution, however i find a work arround. But i can't paste it because the question is closed. Well in short i store in sharedpreferences if i was tooking picture and then when app restarts i check if that's true and go to the view where i was taking picture. That happens becasue when u take 8mb image it closes all apps in background including the one that start taking picture, but then it restarts it.